# Inline assembly; Bitwise operation on float; What's going awry here?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

This simple piece of code is my problem:

Extended asm (gcc); Intel syntax (-masm=intel); Platform - x86

What it should do: Return a float with length of one and the sign (+-) the same as x's.

```
    float signf(float x)
    {
      float r = 1;
      asm volatile (
            "and %1,0x80000000;"
            "or %0,%1;"
            :"=r"(r):"r"(x));
      return r;
    }
```

Calling it with an arbitrary random number chosen by a fair dice roll gives:

```
    signf of -1352353.3253: -5.60519e-045
```

Comment: It would probably be most useful if you looked at the bit representation of all the numbers that are involved (including the one you are attempting to generate)

Comment: @PlasmaHH, a good place to go for that is http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/

Comment: -1352353.3253:
11001001101001010001010100001011
-5.60519e-045:
10000000000000000000000000000100
1:
00111111100000000000000000000000

That's what the binary looks for those numbers. No idea on the problem though.

Comment: @Eximius: obviously the returned value contains garbage from somewhere else, so your assembly doesn't do what you think it does. Looking at the disassembled function might show how it deviates from what you think you gave it.

Answer (score 5):

The actual problem with your inline asm is that you declare `r` as output only, so the compiler will optimize away the initialization. You should use `"+r"` constraint instead of `"=r"` and it should work.

A better optimized version could look like:

```
float signf(float x)
{
    float r;
    __asm__  __volatile__ (
            "and %0, 0x80000000;"
            "or %0, 0x3f800000;"
            :"=r"(r):"0"(x));
    return r;
}
```

Note that this function involves float->int->float conversion (through memory) which may affect performance.

The C version of the above code is:

```
float signf(float x)
{
    union { float f; int i; } tmp, res;
    tmp.f = x;
    res.f = 1;
    res.i |= tmp.i & 0x80000000;
    return res.f;
}
```

This generates identical code for me (using gcc 4.4.5).

The simple C approach `return x < 0 ? -1 : 1;` generates full FPU code without conversion or memory accesses (except for loading the operand) so might perform better. It also uses `fcmov` if available to avoid branching. Needs some benchmarking.

Comment: +1 for *using assembly may affect performance [negatively]*. Comes as a surprise to many users.

Comment: @BoPersson: Thanks. And we haven't even looked at inlined performance where the compiler may further optimize the C code, while it must treat the asm as an unchangeable black box. As an extreme example, `fabs(signf(x))` can be optimized to constant `1` but not when using the asm version.

Answer (score 4):

There are two C++ functions for this in C++11:

```
bool std::signbit (x);
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit

or,

```
float f = std::copysign (1.0f, x);
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/copysign

Comment: I did know about them, but the first one is a bool ( so not much better than just if(myfloat < 0 ) and second one takes a 'magnitude' argument which is superfluous. (Also copy_sign doesn't seem to reside on the gcc that I have (it's not old))

Comment: @Eximius the comparison to zero does not capture the special floating point value of `-0.0f` although it does work with `-INFINITY` and is a bit bogus with `NAN`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work well (AT&T syntax):

```
float signf(float x)
{
  float r = 1;
  asm ("andl $0x80000000, %1\n"
       "\torl %1, %0\n"
       :"+r"(r):"r"(x));
  return r;
}
```

TBH, I would use `copysignf()` as suggested by others. What you are trying to do is unportable both because it is tied only to IA-32 platform and C++ compilers that can do this `asm()` statement.

*EDIT 1*

BTW, the following version works the same (and generates pretty much the same instructions as the above `asm()` statement) and is free of non-portable stuff and type aliasing issues (unlike the `union` based or `reinterpret_cast<>` based versions suggested by others).

```
float signf3(float x)
{
  unsigned u;
  std::memcpy(&u, &x, sizeof (u)) ;

  float r = 1.f;
  unsigned uone;
  std::memcpy(&uone, &r, sizeof (uone));

  uone |= u & 0x80000000;

  std::memcpy(&r, &uone, sizeof (r));
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged C++ so I'll offer two C++ suggestions that you can let your compiler optimize:

- `return x < 0.0f ? -1.0f : 1.0f;`
- `return x / std::abs(x);  // I believe self-division shouldn't cause 'almost 1.0' numbers to be genereated`

Comment: Do these both capture `-0.0f`?

Comment: Do either capture the sign of `-0.0f`?  I don't think so: for `-0.0`, the first will return `1.0f`, and the second `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use asm for this. The following does what you tried to do (even the correct result for -0.0f).

```
float signf(float x) {
    bool sign=(0!=(*(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(&x)) & 0x80000000));
    return sign? -1.0f : 1.0f;
}
```

Comment: even though "std::signbit" should work as well. if you need a float just use "std::signbit(x)? -1.0f : 1.0f". std::signbit should do exactly what my first line does and return true if the sign is set, be it -0.0 or any other number.

Comment: -1 because float is not 64 bits wide on most systems. and because it breaks aliasing rules, AFAIK.

Comment: @wilx you are right. i fixed the 64bits to 32bits (which is the most common size of a float afaik). Don't see any problem with it then (on the contrary, it does exactly what the asm code of eximius was supposed to do, including the same limitation to 32bit floats due to the 0x80000000 constant).